# Python Beginner Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

what is the use of the = in the regex (?=.*?[A-Z]) and why are the ? and * in front of the [a-z] because I saw in a book that they should appear behind the word or expression they should take effect on and why the two ?

Answer (score 0):

This whole RegEx

```
(?=.*?[A-Z])
```

is called a **lookahead assertion**, a kind of lookarounds.

It consists of three items:

```
(?=   )
.*?
[A-Z]
```

The first one is the syntax for a lookahead assertion. The pattern would come in the brackets, after the initial `?=`.

The second one is a dot that matches any character, with a repetition modifier `*?`, where the asserisk means "zero or more matches" and the question mark means "match as few as possible" instead of being greedy.

The third one I suppose you know it.

A lookaround assertion restricts the surrounding of a pattern without matching (capturing) extra things. For example:

```
a(?=b)
```

will match the letter a in `ab`, but not `ac`. Note it only matches the letter `a`, and the letter `b` is only a restriction about *where* the letter `a` should be matched. Whereas `a(b)` matches both letters in `ab` and captures the latter.